# Angular render template without binding

Tags: angularjs

I've been at a loss on how to render an angular template completely to HTML without bindings.

Example:

```
scope.value1 = 99;
scope.value2 = "cat";
scope.div_class = "red-cell";

var template = '<div class="{{ div_class }}">{{ value1 }}, {{ value2 }}</div>';
var linkFn = $compile(template);
var content = linkFn(scope);

console.log(content);
```

Output is a DOM element with angular bindings:

```
<div class="{{ div_class }} ng-binding ng-scope">{{ value1 }}, {{ value2 }}</div>
```

What I want is a rendered element *without* bindings:

```
<div class="red-cell">99, cat</div>
```

I am aware of one-time bindings. However, since I'm handling a lot of the rendering already, I think this is cleaner than a bunch of 1TB in my template.

Is this possible in angular?

**Clarification:** I want to render a template to static HTML. There will be many variables, so it needs to render with a scope/context.

Comment: var template = '<div>99</div>';

Comment: String concatenation? `var template = '<div>' + scope.value + '</div>';`

Comment: @RPGillespie, while that will work, it breaks the convenience of templating. Imagine doing that with 100 variables.

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining what you mean by "doing that with 100 variables". Could you scale it up to 2 or 3 variables so I can get a better idea of what you mean?

Comment: @TechMedicNYC How is your example of the template with 3 variables any more convenient than string concatenating the 3 into the template? String concatenation is actually the same amount of typing because you don't need `{{}}` for every variable, but you do need `"++"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<div>{{ value }}</div>`, could you try `<div ng-bind-html="value"></div>` and see if it works?

Comment: I'm going to have a lot of variables, and by definition `ng-bind-html` is a two way binding. So this does not achieve my goal.

Comment: In that case for single binding, you can do  - `<div ng-bind-html="::value"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to have generated classes added to the rendered html, then you need to:
 1. either not have bindable content in the template.
 2. or you need to have debuginfoenabled as false:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

Comment: It's not about the `ng-*` classes. It's about rendering a template to static HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If static html is what you want, then just make sure you have a static template:

```
scope.value1 = 99;
scope.value2 = "cat";
scope.div_class = "red-cell";

var template = '<div class="{{ div_class }}">{{ value1 }}, {{ value2 }}</div>';
convertToStatic(template, scope); //regex find \{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\} and replace with scope[$1] where $1 is the regex capture group
var linkFn = $compile(template);
var content = linkFn(scope);

console.log(content);
```